# Incorrect order of checking the close vote reasons?

Tags: discussion, subjective, vote-to-close, moderation

See the close votes and comments on the question [When will IE6 be irrelevant?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/815/when-will-ie6-be-irrelevant):

> - Off topic (2)
> - Not constructive (1)
> - Not a real question (1)

> Can you edit this question to meet "Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions"?
>
> Which guidelines of the big 6 do you think this question apply? Gradually we will close questions that doesn't fit on the 6 Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions. If you think your question doesn't meet enough points it would be a good thing the author of the question initiate the close process. Otherwise community or moderators can take the initiative if they they consider this question inappropriate to this site. Thank you. See more: blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective Maybe an edit turns it more suitable to guidelines.

Are people now checking the 6-Q guidelines **before checking whether the question is off-topic**?

Those people can't change their vote to off-topic, so this question stays open while it shouldn't...

How can we prevent this behavior? Should we make the vote reasons more clear?

---

PS: It would be so useful to be able to [contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) [another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users) [user](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/389/bigown) somehow, then this didn't have to be so public.